# Post pic on wall with message with Android Facebook SDK 3.0

Tags: android, facebook

How can i post message along with Picture using Facebook SDK 3.0 on Android,

The link -> can post small pic with link and all other information.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/

What i want, is only to post Pic on wall with message, not a link with description ? 
I want grab screen shot of my current Android screen that i did and saved it into SD card, i need to post it with message on custom button click.

How can i do this with Facebook SDK 3.0 for android ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the Graph API to post photos to a user's wall.

See the [reference page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) for more details.

In the Facebook SDK, you would use the [Request class](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request) to make Graph API calls.

You can use the newUploadPhotoRequest method to add a photo.

If you want to add a description as well, try setting the "message" parameter:

```
Request photoRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(...);
Bundle params = photoRequest.getParameters();
params.putString("message", "description  goes here");
photoRequest.executeAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks Ming, i used newUploadPhotoRequest(Session session, File file, Request.Callback callback) and it is posting Photo on wall, but it doesnt accept the Description for that Photo, how can i add it ?

Comment: are you putting it in the "message" field? If so, then it could be a bug.

Comment: i mean i want to upload Photo along with its description, the link you given " https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request " has method, newUploadPhotoRequest, which i have used,and it is working, it has Photo parameter but not the Description, how can i add Description along with Photo ? and can you tell me How to use Graph api for Facebook sdk 3.0 ? how to use - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos ?

Comment: how can we add link?? I tried using `params.putString("link", "url");` it didn't works for me

Comment: There's no "link" property for photo uploads.

Comment: Hello Ming Li i want to post the picture on my Friend's wall then how i can solve my problem, i get error like this Facebook Error:(#200) this app is not allowed to publish to other user's timeline.
Please help me

Comment: You cannot post on a friend's wall. That functionality has been removed from Facebook's APIs.

Comment: @MingLi I tried this method but neither the message or description appear with the photo, just the photo is uploaded

Comment: hi i am able to post photos successfully,
but the problem is, it is not posting on wall...
it goes to albums with "Only Me" availability....I want to post it publically

Answer (score 0):

Facebook changed this implementation for there version 2 Graph API requests, they recommend a Custom Story instead of posting (if you have your own content to put on the wall of the facebook user beside his comment, or even without his comment)

documentation goes here :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/open-graph?locale=en_GB

just an error in the documentation, the facebook Open Graph objects are refered to by a colon, and not a dot, for example

they mention an open graph Object named "book" in a work space named "books" that way

```
"books.book"
```

the correct way is

```
"books:book"
```

and after you finish implementation you will need to review your application to facebook, which it's documentation goes here as well

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review?locale=en_GB

i really hate facebook documentation, it sucks