# Share photo to facebook user wall using android

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

How can i post message along with Picture using Facebook SDK 3.0 on Android,

The link -> can post small pic with link and all other information.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/feed-dialog/

What i want, is only to post Pic on wall with message, not a link with description ?, i need to post it with message on custom button click.

```
private void publishStory() {


        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){


            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }



            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {

                fis = new FileInputStream(imagepath);

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
             ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
              byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();



            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("message", "Facebook SDK for Android ");

              postParams.putByteArray("source",byteArray);

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("JSON error ","JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();

                    if (error != null) {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.getErrorMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), postId,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams,HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use newUploadPhotoRequest() method of the Facebook **Request** class. Please refer the accepted answer at [Post pic on wall with message with Android Facebook SDK 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110942/post-pic-on-wall-with-message-with-android-facebook-sdk-3-0)